# The difference from the present tense and the present-perfect tense in an adverb clause

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, adverbial-phrases

I learnt at school that you use the present tense in an adverb clause even if you mention the future, but I often encounter adverb clauses with the present-perfect tense.  I would like to know the difference between the two.

- 1-1. I'm going to Rome when I have finished my Italian lessons.
- 1-2. I'll go shopping if it has stopped raining by this afternoon.
- 1-3. Don't drive a car when you haven't had enough sleep.

These three sentences are from my English textbook at school.  What is the difference between the sentences above and below?

- 2-1. I'm going to Rome when I finish my Italian lessons.
- 2-2. I'll go shopping if it stops raining by this afternoon.
- 2-3. Don't drive a car when you don't have enough sleep.

My textbook doesn't describe the difference.  I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences in (1) imply a *state* - you will be able to speak reasonably good Italian, the weather will be fine, you are tired because you haven't had enough sleep.

(2-1) and (2-2) are possible (you will set off for Rome as soon as the lessons finish, you will go out as soon as the rain stops).

(2-3) doesn't really work, because you are talking about how well you slept the previous night. You could say *Don't drive a car when you are not getting enough sleep*, meaning that most of your nights are sleepless.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, the first two sentences in groups 1 and 2 are identical. There's no reason I can think of why someone would choose, say, 1-1 over 2-1 or the other way around. If I said those two sentences one after the other, a native speaker might not notice they were two different sentences.

With 1-3 and 2-3, however, there's a slight difference, which is because of the meaning of "have sleep". In that context, "have sleep" is an action verb meaning something like "do sleep", rather than indicating possession of a quantity of sleep. So in the simple present, which has the meaning of *doing things in general*, sentence 2-3 means something like:

> Don't drive a car when you don't *get enough regular sleep in general*.

This doesn't mean the same thing as:

> Don't drive a car when you are sleepy

which is the intent of 1-3.